# The method createExtendedColor() is undefined for the type CreationHelper (in apachi poi)

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-poi

I am trying to create ExtendedColor  out of sheet, but it throws error that The method createExtendedColor() is undefined for the type CreationHelper.
it also throws error 2.The method createConditionalFormattingRule(String) in the type SheetConditionalFormatting is not applicable for the arguments (ExtendedColor). 3.The method getDataBarFormatting() is undefined for the type ConditionalFormattingRule.

> Thanks in advance

```
    public void conditionalFormatting(Sheet sheet) {
    SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

    ExtendedColor color =  sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createExtendedColor();
    color.setARGBHex("FF63BE7B");
    CellRangeAddress[] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B2:B7") };
    ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(color);
    DataBarFormatting db1 = rule1.getDataBarFormatting();
    db1.getMinThreshold().setRangeType(RangeType.MIN);
    db1.getMaxThreshold().setRangeType(RangeType.MAX);
    sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);

}
```

}

Comment: Check the API docs [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/SheetConditionalFormatting.html) and [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ConditionalFormattingRule.html#getDataBarFormatting()). You are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: See [the Apache POI FAQ entry on missing methods](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) - you are not using the version of Apache POI you think you are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, in pom.xml i had two dependencies, I have removed old one. I have only one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17_1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you using an old version? Why not the latest, currently 3.16?

Comment: because there was a red exclamation symbol on my project file when I change it to 3.16_1. After that I have removed the C:\Users\user\.m2\repository file. Now it is working with 3.16

Comment: The latest release now is Apache POI 3.17!

Comment: Last week I have updated the lib to 3.17. The reason I could not update It  before throwing some error with XSSFColor(byte[]) is undefined , SOLID_FOREGROUNG and BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field. thank you for prompt reply, Gagravarr